# Recursive function to generate permutations correctly prints each permutation but can not add it to a list

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, permutation

The following recursive function generates all permutations of numbers in a given range(n).  Each permutation starts as an empty list.  The function adds the numbers one-by-one and recursively generates partial permutations.  When a permutation reaches length n, it has fully grown and is printed.  All of this works correctly. The problems is that I can not append each permutation to a list of permutations.  It just adds an empty list. What gives? Incidentally, I also wrote the same code in Java and have the same problem.

```
permutations = []

def generate_permutations(n, perm=[]):
    """
    Recursive function to print all possible permutations of integers in range n.  
    :param perm: list representing a single permutation of integers in range(n)
    :param n: end of range(n) and length of each permutation
    """
    # base case: when a permutation reaches its full length, print it and move on:
    if len(perm) == n:
        print(perm)
        permutations.append(perm)  # does not work. Adds an empty list.
        return 
    # recursive case:
    for k in range(n):
        # if number k not already in the permutation, add it, generate permutations, and
        # then remove k so a new set of permutations can be generated.
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)
            generate_permutations(n, perm)
            perm.pop()
```

The following calls generate the following output:

```
generate_permutations(4)
print("______")
print(permutations)

[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 2]
[0, 2, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
[1, 0, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 0]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
______
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: `permutations.append(perm.copy())`  or `permutations.append(list(perm))` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You append `perm` to `permutations` then remove the elements in `perm` using `pop()`. This will remove those in `permutations` as it is not a copy of `perm` that is present in  `permutations` but it is a reference to `perm` itself.

The concept of **references**, is similar to **pointers** in **C**.

```
object_1 = object_2
```

saves a reference of `object_2` to `object_1`  not a copy so any change in `object_2` will reflect in `object_1`

use `copy.deepcopy()` to copy the list `perm`

**Working code:**

```
import copy
permutations = []

def generate_permutations(n, perm=[]):
    """
    Recursive function to print all possible permutations of integers in range n.
    :param perm: list representing a single permutation of integers in range(n)
    :param n: end of range(n) and length of each permutation
    """
    # base case: when a permutation reaches its full length, print it and move on:
    if len(perm) == n:
        print(perm)
        permutations.append(copy.deepcopy(perm))  
        return
    # recursive case:
    for k in range(n):
        # if number k not already in the permutation, add it, generate permutations, and
        # then remove k so a new set of permutations can be generated.
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)
            generate_permutations(n, perm)
            perm.pop()

generate_permutations(3)
print(permutations)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```